# Populating an array of ranges using the ADDRESS function in Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, range, vba

I have defined a two dimensional array of ranges that I wish to populate with references to a specific set of cells (the criteria for which are irrelevant). I have tried using the pseudo code below, but have come up with syntax-related errors:

```
    Dim ArrayOfRanges() as Range
    ReDim ArrayofRanges (10,1)

    For i = 1 to 10        

    Set ArrayOfRanges(i, 0) = Range(WorksheetFunction.Address(Row(i),Column(i))
    Set ArrayOfRanges(i, 1) = Range(WorksheetFunction.Address(Row(i),Column(i))

    Next i
```

Does anyone know how I can populate the array correctly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use following code:

```
Dim ArrayOfRanges() As Range
ReDim ArrayOfRanges(10, 1)

For i = 1 To 10

    Set ArrayOfRanges(i, 0) = Cells(i, i)
    Set ArrayOfRanges(i, 1) = Cells(i, i)

Next i
```